# Labels not rendering with fonts from custom tileserver

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm running an instance of tileserver GL to serve up custom map styles, and I want to use those styles in mapbox-gl-js.

Unfortunately, none of the labels on the map is rendering, and there aren't any errors in the console. I see the requests to the server's glyph endpoint in the server logs are successful, and the requests in the network tab of the developer console are all 200s.

It really seems like all of the pieces are in working order, as when going through the tileserver's demo site, the labels are rendered just fine.

Are there additional steps that are needed to get mapbox-gl-js to work with a glyphs endpoint that isn't from mapbox?

Comment: Check for multiple fonts in your style. I found I could only have one font listed per label/text.

Comment: Did you set "serveAllFonts": true in tileserver gl config.json file?